# File upload php isset script isn't printing out uploaded file data

Tags: php

I just wanted to see whether its uploading in a temp directory or not.. but all it shows is empty blank white page.. 
though the submit button redirects the page to upload.php it shows nothing, no error, no warning.. nothing..

Any suggestions are helpful..

My HTML form:;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="upload.php" method="post" encrypt="multipart/form-data">                                                     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="color:black;" ><strong>Upload</strong></label>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file" placeholder="Upload " required>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

upload.php::

```
<?php
if(isset($FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    print_r($file);
}
?>
```

I just wanted to see whether its uploading in a temp directory or not.. but all it shows is empty blank white page.. 
though the submit button redirects the page to upload.php it shows nothing, no error, no warning.. nothing..

Any suggestions are helpful..

Comment: There are probably an error logged somewhere, check your apache log files, or change your php configuration to show errors on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few errors.

1. Upload file check is if(isset(**$_FILES**['file'])) not if(isset(**$FILES**['file'])).
2. form **enctype** not **encrypt**

->. to get the temp name/path you can use `$temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

I tried this code it's work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    print("Temp path : $temp_name <br>");
    print_r($_FILES['file']);
}
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                                     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="color:black;" ><strong>Upload</strong></label>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file" placeholder="Upload " required>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Yo must also configure `php.ini` (`file_uploads = On`) to accept file upload.

To install php follow : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/178/how-to-install-php-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

You can check is a file uploaded or not using is_uploaded_file function`enter code here`

In your case the "FILE_FIELD_NAME is **"file"** so you can check using following line

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
```

After then you can print file name or anything that supports through `$_FILES` super global array.

Comment: i added your line below `$file = $_FILES['file'];` but it still showing blank page..

Comment: 1. you need to check is file uploaded? so replace if(isset($FILES['file'])) with if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))

Comment: if this doesn't work check file uploading is enabled in your php settings

Comment: i have this code in the upload.php... `$file = $_FILES['file'];
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
 print_r($file);` it is saying unidentifies index file... what does it mean..

Comment: Change form attribute "encrypt" to "enctype" and then try again

Comment: Great. best of luck